# form input come as readonly on first load Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, laravel-8

I noticed this weird behaviour when a navigate to `/login` and `/register` using `router-link`.

The form loads fine, but it doesn't allow me to add data on it, I have to refresh the page to activate the form input fields.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="form mt-6" @submit.prevent="register" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
            <input type="text" v-model="form.firstName" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                 id="first-name-field" placeholder="Primeiro nome" autocomplete="off" />
            <HasError :form="form" field="firstName" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
            <input type="text" v-model="form.lastName" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                id="last-name-field" placeholder="Último nome" autocomplete="off" />
            <HasError :form="form" field="lastName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-5">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.phone_number" class="form-control form-control-lg"
            id="phone-field" placeholder="Número de celular" autocomplete="off" />
        <HasError :form="form" field="phone_number" />
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
            <input type="password" v-model="form.password" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                id="password-field" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="off" />
            <HasError :form="form" field="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 my-2">
            <input type="password" v-model="form.password_confirmation" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                id="pass-confirm-field" placeholder="Confirmar senha" autocomplete="off" />
            <HasError :form="form" field="password_confirmation" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <Button :form="form" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3">Registar</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <p class="py-3 primary-color">
                Possue uma conta?
                <router-link to="/login">Faça login.</router-link>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                phone_number: "",
                password: "",
                password_confirmation: ""
            }),

            login() {
                this.form.post("/api/auth/register").then(({ data }) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    // window.location.href = '/home';
                });
            }
        };
    },
    created() {
        // console.log('Created');
    },
    mounted() {
        // console.log("Login mounted");
    }
};
</script>
```

And this is what i get when I inspect the code on `DevTools`:

```
<input data-v-51f045bf="" type="text" id="first-name-field"
    placeholder="Primeiro nome" autocomplete="off" 
    class="form-control form-control-lg"
    readonly="readonly" <---------------------------- I FIND THIS
    style="background-color: inherit;">
```

Using Laravel 8 & Vue 2.6.12

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your script codes but this may help.

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            values: [],
            form: {
               email: '',first_name: '',last_name: '',password : '',terms: '', password_confirmation: '', device_name: 'browser',
            },
            error:null,
           errors:[]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        registerUser(){
            axios.post('/register', this.form).then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('user_data', response.data.token)
                this.$router.push({ name: 'Dashboard'})
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                if (errors.response.status === 500) {
                 this.error = 'Something went Wrong, Please try Again'
            }
            })
        },        
    }    
}
</script>
```

this is my working code, in my case, just look on `data()`, something must be wrong there

**UPDATE**

since you updated your question this should be it

```
data() {
        return {
            form:{   //change this
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                phone_number: "",
                password: "",
                password_confirmation: ""
            },

            login() {
                this.form.post("/api/auth/register",this.form).then((response =>{  //if it will not post change this line too.
                    console.log(response.data);
                    // window.location.href = '/home';
                });
            }
        };
    },
```

and remove `mounted()` and `created()`, you dont need them, since you dont mount anything in your application, when the application loads, they might be causing problems

Comment: I am able to send data through the form, the problem is that when I load it from `router-link`, inputs are `readonly`.

Comment: please edit your question with <script></script> code. I maybe able to help. And which version of vue are you using

Comment: I edited the post with requested info @WillianBaduu

Comment: I have edited the answer too, I hope it will work now, remember to mark my answer as accepted once it works

Comment: I am using vform, so I need `form: new Form({});`. Read https://vform.vercel.app/

Comment: try removing `created()` and `mounted()`, if it still leading to problem try not using vforms and use my methods